# Wordpress Custom Rewrite Rule in Functions.php

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to add a custom rewrite rule in the functions to handle some new features that I dont want to use query strings. I had this but it doesnt seem to be working

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse26388_rewrites_init' );

function wpse26388_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'books/([^/]+/?',
        'index.php?pagename=books&book_name=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse26388_query_vars' );
function wpse26388_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'book_name';

    return $query_vars;
}
```

basically I want to catch site.org/books/ANYTHING/ and point it to another template and use the `book_name` query in there. But as of now anything after `/books/` results in a 404 error and I am not sure how to pass in a page-template.php file to use.

Comment: Missing the closing parentheses `'books/([^/]+)/?',`

Comment: @slapyo I see them in my code no?

Comment: you have `'books/([^/]+/?',` ... should be `'books/([^/]+)/?',`

Comment: @slapyo sorry I was thinking ''  not ()

Comment: @slapyo do add another one after that (so /books/SOMETHING/ANOTHER) can I just double that rewrite rule like: 
`add_rewrite_rule(
        'books/([^/]+/?)/([^/]+/?)',
      'index.php?pagename=([^/]+/?)&article_name=$matches[1]',
        'top' );`

Comment: It would look like this I think `'books/([^/]+)/?([^/]+)/?',`. The `/?` part means the slash is optional. That should match it if it was books/123, books/123/, books/123/abc, and books/123/abc/.

Comment: did you reset your permalink after? you have to flush the permalink before the rule will take effect, you can call ```flush_rewrite_rules()``` function to flush the permalink, also try printing the global ```$wp_rewrite``` on wp_head and see if your rule is in there